# What is the difference between 妳 (nǐ) and 他 (tā)

Tags: difference

Wiktionary gives the meaning "you" for the character 妳 (nǐ), and tā (either 他 or 她).

Is there a formal / informal difference? Which should I prefer in general usage?

Comment: Wiktionary (1) does not give the reading `hăi` for `妳` and (2) does not give the meaning "you" for `tā`. Please revise the question - as of now it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oops! I was dealing with a notepad full of chinese characters on the train via my phone's copy and paste. I must have mixed them up.

Answer (score 2):

妳 is in theory a feminine form of 你, but it's rare because not many people care about the supposed masculinity of the 亻element.
他 and 她 are 'he' and 'she' respectively, as any reasonable dictionary will tell you. There is a formal/informal distinction for 'you', but it's 你(normal) and 您(formal).

Whatever your sources are for the reading 'hai' and the meaning 'you' for 他, you should ditch 'em, they're unreliable.

Comment: It’s so fluid!!